# __slots__ of `property` type

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, python-internals

So what's the deal with python `property` type? It doesn't have either `__slots__` or `__dict__`. But `__dict__` of `property` type shows slot references.

```
In [28]: p = property(lambda: 5)

In [29]: hasattr(p, '__slots__')
Out[29]: False

In [30]: hasattr(p, '__dict__')
Out[30]: False

In [31]: type(p).__dict__
Out[31]: 
<dictproxy {'__delete__': <slot wrapper '__delete__' of 'property' objects>,
 '__doc__': <member '__doc__' of 'property' objects>,
 '__get__': <slot wrapper '__get__' of 'property' objects>,
 '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'property' objects>,
 '__init__': <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'property' objects>,
 '__new__': <function __new__>,
 '__set__': <slot wrapper '__set__' of 'property' objects>,
 'deleter': <method 'deleter' of 'property' objects>,
 'fdel': <member 'fdel' of 'property' objects>,
 'fget': <member 'fget' of 'property' objects>,
 'fset': <member 'fset' of 'property' objects>,
 'getter': <method 'getter' of 'property' objects>,
 'setter': <method 'setter' of 'property' objects>}>
```

Additionally I've tried to inherit from property to add additional attribute, but obvious method messed things up.

```
In [37]: property_ = type('property_', (property, ), dict(__slots__=('prop', )))

In [38]: p_ = property_(lambda: 5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-06c5a90565ef> in <module>()
----> 1 p_ = property_(lambda: 5)

AttributeError: 'property_' object attribute '__doc__' is read-only
```

If `property` does not implement `__slots__` feature, why i can't assign attribute to `property` instance?

```
In [45]: p = property(lambda: 'prop')

In [46]: p.attr = 'attr'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-71284e3de202> in <module>()
----> 1 p.attr = 'attr'

AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'attr'
```

Comment: `property` is implemented in C, and behaves much like many other types implemented in C (`object`, `set`, `list`, ...). Those slots you see are C slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__slots__` mechanism exposes an *already used feature* for C types, to Python types. The objects with `slot` in their name on a `property` do not imply that it uses the `__slots__` feature. They are just objects that are using the C type feature.

The `property` object can just be subclassed without using `__slots__`:

```
>>> class Foo(property):
...     prop = 'bar'
...
>>> def test(self): return 'success'
...
>>> Foo(test).__get__(object())
'success'
>>> Foo(test).prop
'bar'
```

Subclassing adds a `__dict__` for instances of that subclass. Or you can easily create the same functionality simply by implementing the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: If it doesn't uses `__slots__` feature, why i can't assign attribute to existing property?

Comment: @GeningD.: because it doesn't have a `__dict__` attribute. That's the reason to use `__slots__`, to create a custom Python class that doesn't have a `__dict__`. C types don't have that restriction, loads of types don't allow attributes. `object()` for example.

Comment: Sorry, i misread your answer. So it's possible for classes write in C don't implement neither `__slots__` or `__dict__` but force strict typing directly from C?

Comment: @GeningD.: `__slots__` is a pure-Python-only feature; it does two things: remove the `__dict__` slot, and inserts dedicated descriptors for your attributes instead. `__dict__` is a slot your pure-Python instances always get unless you disabled it by using `__slots__`. C types have to add it explicitly; see the [function object definition](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/funcobject.c#l330) for an example.

Comment: @GeningD.: neither of these features have anything to do with strict typing.